# laravel 5 : scalable relationship between more than 4 tables

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5, relationship

I'm working on a E-learning project and want to build a scalable relationships between tables but stuck on how to map them using eloquent relationship.
i have 5 table

```
 1. boards : id, name(field names)
 2. standards: id, board_id, name
 3. subjects: id, board_id, standard_id, name
 4. chapters: id, board_id, standard_id, subject_id , name
 5. questionTypes: id, type(like MCQ, T/F, Fill in the blanks)
 6. questions: id,board_id, standard_id, subject_id, chapter_id, question_type_id, question
```

**Description about structure**

- boards represents the study board mean state board and all
- standards represents the class example: 1st 2nd etc
- subjects is like `math` , `science` etc
- chapters is like number system of math subject
- question_types represents type of question in this project i have 3 types of question but it can be more
- questions table contains all the questions of chapter depending upon `board`, `standard`, `subject` .

I'm using laravel 5 and i'm a newbee in eloquent relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create models for each table:
`php artisan make:model Board`

**Note:** Laravel knows to pluralize your model so Model Board becomes Table boards.  This also works for words like: Copy/copies, etc.

Artisan also creates a migration file for each model you create.

In this migration, you need to define foreign keys.

```
Schema::create('boards', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });


Schema::create('standards', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('board_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('board_id')->references('id')->on('boards')->onDelete('cascade');
        });

Schema::create('subjects', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('board_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('standard_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('board_id')->references('id')->on('boards')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('standard_id')->references('id')->on('subjects')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

etc...

And in each Model file, you define the relationship:

```
<?php 

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Board extends Model {

    protected $fillable = [];

    public function standards()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Standard');
    }

    public function subjects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Subject');
    }


    ...


}
```

And in the other models:

```
<?php 

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Standard extends Model {

    protected $fillable = [];

    public function board()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Board');
    }


}


<?php 

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Subject extends Model {

    protected $fillable = [];

    public function board()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Board');
    }

    public function standard()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Standard');
    }

    ...


}
```

Now, in Laravel, you can do something like:

`Board::find(1)->subjects` or `Subject::find(4)->board`

Hope this helps!

Comment: well i got basic idea for relationship but a 
Standard can have many board like 1st standard can be any board
and a subject can have many standard and board,
same for the chapters and questions .
so should i use 
hasMany() relationsip in standard , subject , chapter and question for board ?

Comment: Oh, i misunderstood.  As far as how to structure your database, you'll have to spend some time to figure out how you'll want to use the data. It's not trivial, and there isn't only one right answer. One you decide, then you'll know how to set it up without a problem. For example,  i think i would make subject the highest level model instead of board. Then Subject has many board, but board belongs to one Subject  (if that is true).

Comment: why you think that Subject should be highest level model?
a board can have many subjects and subject can have many boards.
and there is much higher level model than subject i.e. Standard.

Comment: Like I said, it's up to you.